# While loop keeps running to receive input

Tags: python

noobie here, I tried making my rock paper scissors game (forgive me for certain choice of variables used in the code) but it keeps on looping at where the input should be taken and doesn't proceed further, can anyone please tell me what's wrong

```
import random


choices = ["rock","paper","scissors"]

computer = random.choice(choices)
player = None

while player not in choices:
    player = input("Please pick one\n rock, paper, or scissors?: ").lower

if player == computer:
    print ("computer: ", computer)
    print ("player: ", player)
    print ("This match is a tie, can't even do something simple, dipshit!")

elif player == "rock":
    if computer == "paper":
        print ("paper wraps rock")
    else:
        print ("rock smashes scissors")

elif player == "paper":
    if computer == "scissors":
        print ("scissors eats up paper's ass lmaoooo")
    else :
        print ("rock gets wrapped by paper")

elif player == "scissors":
    if computer == "rock":
        print ("damn boi that computer rock eating up yo damn ass pfttt")
    else :
        print ("snip, snip, time to go paper boiiiii")
```

I tried adding an if statement to break out the loop if it finds that the string given was valid but it still keeps on looping, I'd be grateful for the help and also don't mind a few pointers on writing a neater program following standard practices, thank you

Comment: too much ass eating, don't you think so? ;)

Comment: a nice exercice Iyou can try to do in order to learn a very useful thing is to rewrite your code using dictionaries. Your code will be greatly simplified and more portable

Comment: Nope, it's never enough @David xD

Comment: will make sure to do so, thanks @SembeiNorimaki this was reaalllyy helpful

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki out of curiosity, what do you mean by more portable? this code can run on any python platform and doesn't have dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change `lower` to `lower()`.

As said [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-invoking-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/) and taking note that *callable* should be *caller* (@slothrop commented it):

> - When we call a function with parentheses, the function gets execute and returns the result to the callable.
> - In another case, when we call a function without parentheses, a function reference is sent to the callable rather than executing the function itself

For example, if we give 'Rock' as input':

- `player.lower()` prints `rock`
- `player.lower` prints `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f89d5caeaf0>`

---

You can also write `while` loop this way, with the use of `:=` (*"the walrus operator"*), as @Sembei Norimaki pointed out:

```py
while (player := input("Please pick one\n rock, paper, or scissors?: ").lower()) not in choices:
    continue

print(player) # e.g. prints 'rock' if you gave sth like 'RocK'
```

Comment: Good answer, might be a little confusiong though

Comment: Ohhh, such a simple mistake, I don't know how I missed that lol, thank you so much

Comment: but here you are not storing the input value anywhere, and it gets lost. You should use the `:=` operator if you want to use the input inside the while

Comment: I removed the mistake as @SembeiNorimaki pointed out.

Comment: your answer was almost right, just use the [:= operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) to assign the input to the variable player

Comment: *"Callable"* in the text you quote should be *"caller"* (I know this is an error in the source, not one you added when quoting it!)